# Difference between visual studio 2013 premium and visual studio shell integrated

Tags: visual-studio, shell

I asked my organisation to install visual studio premium version.They have installed visual studio 2013 shell integrated.I tried to open a web application it is not loading .
Asked the Installation team they are claiming that shell integrated visual studio is the premium one.

I wanted to know whether visual studio 2013 premium and shell integrated version is the same

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio integrated shell is a way to distribute the Visual Studio application with features and customization.

It includes the integrated development environment (IDE), debugger, and source control integration. However, it does not include any programming languages, you must add them as needed, which may be the reason why you can't load your web application.

Regarding the edition I do not know if you can find the edition used to generate the distribution. Keep in mind that some functions may have been removed (or added) in the customization process. In the end you might have to trust them that you are using the 2013 premium edition.